# WMF 5.0 (April Preview) DSC Pull Server Installation fails

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, powershell-v5.0

I am trying to install The DSC-Service Windows Feature on a Windows 2012 R2 machine with WMF 5.0 already installed. The installation fails with the following errors:

*Install-WindowsFeature DSC-Service*:

> Install-WindowsFeature : The request to add or remove features on the specified server failed.
> Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed.
> The source files could not be downloaded.
> Use the "source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature.

*dism.exe /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:DSC-Service*

> The source files could not be downloaded.
> Use the "source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature.

And in CBS.log

> Not able to find package: Microsoft-PowerShell-DSC-PullServer-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.2.9600.853 from the cached windows update index. [HRESULT = 0x800f090d - CBS_E_MISSING_PACKAGE_MAPPING_INDEX]
>
> The mapping index cache was refreshed recently, skip.
>
> Failed to find package: Microsoft-PowerShell-DSC-PullServer-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.2.9600.853 from the index with mapping index packages recently rebuilt,  [HRESULT = 0x800f090d - CBS_E_MISSING_PACKAGE_MAPPING_INDEX]
>
> Failed to get WU category/updateID for package: Microsoft-PowerShell-DSC-PullServer-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.2.9600.853 [HRESULT = 0x800f090d - CBS_E_MISSING_PACKAGE_MAPPING_INDEX]
>
> Failed to get the category and update ID for package: Microsoft-PowerShell-DSC-PullServer-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.2.9600.853, component: amd64_microsoft.powershell.dsc.pullserver_31bf3856ad364e35_7.2.9600.853_none_469d713f35e0208c, file: IISSelfSignedCertModule.dll [HRESULT = 0x800f090d - CBS_E_MISSING_PACKAGE_MAPPING_INDEX]
>
> Exec: Missing files are found during staging attempt but failed to download content from WU. [HRESULT = 0x800f090d - CBS_E_MISSING_PACKAGE_MAPPING_INDEX]

I tried also installing .NET 3.5 (to see if sources are downloaded at all) and that works well.

Is there some place or way to get the DSC-Service sources for installing the pull server on Windows 2012 R2 with WMF 5.0?

Answer (score 1):

The error has been resolved - root cause was an Windows Image from which the machine was installed, where Windows Features are not only beeing "not installed" but also "removed".
Apparently Windows and the update mechanism do not handle that situation well.